# EC2 and Mongo, best practices

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, mongodb

When hosting web applications with EC2 is it best practice to use a separate EC2 instance for the database (mongo in this case) or is it ok just to keep the web server and database server on the same instance?

Comment: Mongo shouldn't really be run on one server, period.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: What @ceejayoz means is that fur effective use of Mongo two servers helps to eliminate fault-tolerance concerns.  Not to mention improves the in-memory performance of the server as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Practice would be to have separate servers for all your tiers (web, db, etc) and on top of that would be multiple, load-balanced servers to provide durability and fault-tolerance.

If it's a small site and you're not worried about scaling, one box with enough ram and CPU would work, but it's not going to be 'best practice' for sure.

If you want a highly available mongodb service, you'll want separate servers and setup a replica set so you have several mongodb boxes available incase something happens to one.